# What are the correct flags for linking to gslcblas libraries when they are not in /usr/local/lib?

Tags: c, makefile, command-line

On my personal laptop I enter

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas equal_runtimes.c particle_filters.c solvers.c -o equal_runtimes
```

in the terminal to compile my C code and have no issues. As far as I know this is because the gsl headers and libraries are on the standard search paths `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` respectively (https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/usage.html).

However, when I try to compile the same code with the above commands on a system in which the headers/libraries are located in `/apps/gsl/2.1/include` and `/apps/gsl/2.1/lib` respectively, I get the warning

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gsl_blas_dgemv’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Therefore it seems the compiler is not linking the gsl libraries, as it's assuming `gsl_blas_dgemv` is my function. To try to fix this I've followed the guidance at the above gnu.org link, for which the best I can come up with is

```
gcc -L/apps/gsl/2.1/lib -std=gnu99 -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas equal_runtimes.c particle_filters.c solvers.c -o equal_runtimes
```

but still no success. Is there an issue with the above syntax I'm using or is there something else here that I'm missing?

Comment: `-L SomePath` tells GCC where to look for library files. To tell it where to look for headers to include, use `-I SomePath`. Also, it would be very strange if your compiler issued a warning about implicit declaration of a function but not also about not being able to find a header file that had been included with `#include`. Did it?

Comment: Yes that is all the information that is provided; only about implicit function declaration. Off the back of what you said I tried to compile with searches for both the headers and libraries but still the same warning.

Comment: Then your source code is missing an `#include` of a header that declares `gsl_blas_dgemv`.

Comment: Note that the order of command-line arguments matters, albeit sometimes more so than others.  Be safe: put the `-l` option for each library *after* all the source files, object files, and other libraries that depend on it.  Under very rare circumstances, this may require you to duplicate one or more `-l` options, and that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @Eric Potpischil's comments, the problem was the wrong header `<gsl/gsl_cblas.h>` being used for `gsl_blas_dgemv` instead of the correct `<gsl/gsl_blas.h>`. This was not an issue on my own system as the blas library would automatically be found by virtue of its location, which was not the case when using the external system.